# IPFS public gateway problem

Tags: solidity, nft, ipfs

I put a 10sec video in my IPFS local node ( after `ipfs daemon` command I've imported the file in my IPFS desktop . now I can see the file on the local host but I cannot see the file on public gateway ( I mean https://ipfs.io ) and the Pinata also cannot find the CID ( but the Pinata's `CID` verifier item can recognize the `CID` ! )
its weird in someway , could anyone help me in this issue ?

Comment: Did you pin your video on your local IPFS node?
https://docs.ipfs.tech/how-to/pin-files/#three-kinds-of-pins

Comment: Are your router or firewall settings blocking outgoing IPFS connections? Is your IPFS daemon running and properly synchronized with the network? Is your content pinned to your local IPFS node? Maybe you could start by looking at these aspect.

Answer (score 1):

This should be due to the ipfs gateway not being able to find your local ipfs node, this can be due to various reasons such as your network, router settings etc. The Pinata's verifier item just recalculates your file into a CID, this doesn't mean that your file has been Pinned on the IPFS network.

It is recommended that you can directly pin your files to IPFS using a product like [Pinata](https://www.pinata.cloud/) or [4EVERLAND](https://www.4everland.org), which will be more convenient!